# jQuery Odd Even is Adding Even to an Odd Element

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

```
jQuery('li.has-sub ul li:even').addClass('even');
jQuery('li.has-sub ul li:odd').addClass('odd');
```

The classes are being added to a drop down menu.  In one drop down menu the classes are added correctly but the another dropdown is adding class `even` to odd elements.  I think that jquery might be counting all of the list items together, which still doesnt explain why it is counting 1 as even.  You can see the problem on this url:

The menu with the yellow background starting with rafting trips.
http://bit.ly/XAEmh7

I have tried adding `this` in an attempt to make jQuery count only the ul in question but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is behaving correctly given your code:

```
jQuery('li.has-sub ul li:even').addClass('even');
jQuery('li.has-sub ul li:odd').addClass('odd');
```

If you change it to:

```
jQuery('li.has-sub').each(function(){
   jQuery('ul li:even',this).addClass('even');
   jQuery('ul li:odd',this).addClass('odd');
});
```

Should work.

Comment: Thanks.  This will work to solve my problem.  But, the odd and evens are still switched.  I mean, the first sub `li` is now even and second odd. I suppose this is because the main `li` is being counted?

Comment: Nope - this is how the :even and :odd selectors work. Referring the jQuery docs ":even selects the first element, third element, and so on within the matched set." and ":odd selects the second element, fourth element, and so on within the matched set.". http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/ and http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

:ODD/:EVEN selectors are 0 based index so it will high-light Second,fourth,etc rows as odd (index 1,3, etc.)

Also, for improving performance you should use .filter as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li ul').filter(':even').addClass('even').end()
              .filter(':odd').addClass('odd');
});
```

Please refer the jQuery documentation : http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/